# sql transformation - rows to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, transformation

i have been trying to solve this one [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y47E7.png)

my initial idea is like this

```
select name,
    CASE
    when count(name) = 1 then get first distinct value
    when count(name) = 2 then get first distinct value
    else get first distinct value
    END  as val1,
    CASE
    when count(name) = 1 then null
    when count(name) = 2 then get second distinct value
    else get second distinct value
    END as val2,
    CASE
    when count(name) = 1 then null
    when count(name) = 2 then null
    else get third distinct value
    END as val3
into desired_table
from source_table
group by name
```

is my attempt feasible? if so, how do i access the first, second and third distinct values?

Comment: please tag your dbms

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

use `pivot` . Your output table was incorrect. The correct form is available in **db<>fiddle**.

```
select name,x as value1,y as value2,z as value3
from
(
  select *
  from t1
) as SourceTable  
pivot
(
   max(value) for value in(x,y,z)
) as PivotTable
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e8680e969419777c109fc698b824ae70)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation along with `row_number()`:

```
select name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as value_3
into desired_table
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by value) as seqnum
      from source_table s
     ) s
group by name;
```